# LibFuzzer: Fuzzing a function that only accepts even length input

Tags: fuzzing

I am currently using LibFuzzer (or more particular, cargo fuzz, but it's just a wrapper around LibFuzzer) in order to fuzz a function that only accepts input of even length. So you can imagine the code being something like this:

```
function toFuzz(String input){
    if((input.length() % 2)==1){
        return 0; // Not equal length 
    }
    // logic goes here
}
```

I do not want to fuzz this particular check - is there any way I can tell libFuzzer to only generate inputs of even length? Or is filtering out even inputs in the test harness the best way to go?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out inputs in the test harness or just call the function and let it do the early return. Either way LibFuzzer will notice that it isn't an "interesting" case and not spend much time on it.